# Failed to load error in Three JS

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I use the addon io_blender to export my 3d model to JSON file. 
but when i try to load in the html show the next error:

three.js:31844 Failed to load file:///F:/xampp/htdocs/threejs/Rock1.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApkWC.png)

readed  a lot of possible solutions, but i don't understand. 
some people said that i need to put the json file on a server. so i copy the files on htdocs from xampp and didn't work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            controls =  new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            var obj;
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load(
                'Rock1.json',
                function(g,m){
                    obj = new THREE.Mesh(g,m);
                    scene.add(obj);

                    obj.position = -6;
                    obj.rotation = 0.4;
                }
            );

            //create the model
            /*var geometry =  new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

            //create material
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: false});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);*/
            //scene.add (cube); 
            camera.position.z = 3;

            //game logic
            var update = function(){
                /*cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
                cube.rotation.y += 0.05;*/
            };

            //draw scene
            var render = function() {
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            //run game loop (update. render, repeat)
            var GameLoop = function(){
                requestAnimationFrame( GameLoop );
                update( );
                render( );
            };

            GameLoop();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: Please read: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: three.js:31844 Failed to load file:///F:/xampp/htdocs/threejs/Rock1.json: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your json file on a **server**, basically this is the solution.

I had the same error and I found the same possibles solutions, I putted the dae file on a server but it didn't work as you said, but in my case I got a different error

*Failed to load https://...test.dae: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

I added this chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) and the problem was fixed.

Your problem is related to json file but I'm sure this solution will be useful.